# Socket.io: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined

Tags: node.js, socket.io

So i am trying to connect multiple users to a room where video can be shared, but I keep getting an error whenever I join a room which is `Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined` which is thrown for the `socket.to(roomId).broadcast.emit('user-connected', userId)` line. I'm not sure what is causing this, and any help would be great. Cheers.

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const server = require('http').Server(app)
const io = require('socket.io')(server)
const { v4: uuidV4 } = require('uuid')

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use(express.static('public'))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect(`/${uuidV4()}`)
})

app.get('/:room', (req, res) => {
  res.render('room', { roomId: req.params.room })
})

io.on('connection', socket => {
  socket.on('join-room', (roomId, userId) => {
    socket.join(roomId)
    socket.to(roomId).broadcast.emit('user-connected', userId)
    // This line here

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
      socket.to(roomId).broadcast.emit('user-disconnected', userId)
    })
  })
})

server.listen(3000)
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To broadcast to all clients in a particular room, just use `socket.to(roomId).emit(...)`. You don't need to use the `.broadcast` property.

Answer (score 18):

If I am right, you are following Web Dev Simplified's Zoom Clone video, I was facing the same issue, but omitting the `.broadcast` property works fine.

Comment: Had the same issue while watching that video.

Answer (score 3):

```
socket.broadcast.to(roomId).emit("user-connected", userId);
```

It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

socket.broadcast.to(roomId).emit("user-connected", userId);

This works because if you use new version of socket.io then it changed the syntax i don't know but previously iI use socket.to(roomId).broadcastsocket.to(roomId).broadcast and it's works but nowadays not work so iI use mension syntax Thank you

Comment: Hi, there is an identical answer, before yours